# Spresense　超音波リアルタイムFFTアナライザーの作成について

Tags: spresense

Spresenseスケッチ例でFFTアナライザーを動かしてみました。

超音波（20kHz～50KHz）までの音をマイクで取得
デジタルフィルタにて低周波帯域（20kHz以下）は減衰、超音波領域（20kHz以上）は増幅し
その結果をリアルタイムでLCDに描画させることはSpresenseのスペック的に可能でしょうか？

ご教示いただければ幸いです。

物品構成
・メイン＆拡張基盤
・LCDディスプレイ
・超音波対応MEMSマイク（アナログ）
　－デジタルマイクでも後ほど試したい

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次のGithubに192kHzまで対応したFFTアナライザのサンプルがあるようです。

https://github.com/TE-YoshinoriOota/Spresense_fftanalyzer_sample

ハイパス・フィルターの設定も20kHzとあるので所望のことができるのではないでしょうか？
ご参考まで。